# MultiColor Gradient in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, gradient

I started learning the Qt framework, and I wanted to create a MultiColored Gradient (like below image) background for the Window:

[image: Sample MutiColored Gradient Image]

I went through the official documentation on `Linear/Conical/Radial/Shape Gradient` QML type and also did Google. But couldn't see any option to achieve this.

Is there any other way to make it possible? Preferably in QML.

**Edit 1:**

As stated in Comments, `GradientStop` can be used for multiple colors. But its can't be used it to produce the result as in the given image.

Comment: LinearGradients can be "multicolored" but not the way you're showing. I'm not aware of anything in QML that would generate that kind of image for you automatically. You might be able be able to build it manually by overlapping blurred rectangles or something, but it looks easier to just use an image file.

Comment: @JarMan Thanks for your input, but the thing is the colors wont be static. Am planning to make it Dynamically change the color every predefined seconds. Actually my target is to make it look like "Breathing" effect. This MultiColored gradient forms the Basis for it. Thats why I asked this without giving much insight.

Comment: Probably need to create your own cpp object to do it and then expose it to qml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first familiarize with Qt example `quick\scenegraph\fboitem`. It demonstrates creating custom QML control with C++/OpenGL backend.

Also you can implement it with `ShaderEffect` QML control. I recommend this site https://www.shadertoy.com/new for debugging your shaders. Also you can use, for example, `Canvas` for passing arrays to your shader as texture (`ShaderEffect` doesn't allow passing arrays normally, https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50493).

Here is possible implementation of your control with dynamic points count, colors and positions.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: "Custom gradient"

    Item {
        anchors.fill: parent

        layer.enabled: true
        layer.effect: ShaderEffect {
            readonly property var dataTex: dataCanvas
            readonly property int count: dataCanvas.colors.length

            fragmentShader: "
                  varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
                  uniform lowp float qt_Opacity;
                  uniform sampler2D dataTex;
                  const uniform lowp int count;
                  void main() {
                      vec3 col = 0.0;

                      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                          vec4 color = texture2D(dataTex, vec2(i / (float)count + 0.01, 0.0));
                          vec2 point = texture2D(dataTex, vec2(i / (float)count + 0.01, 1.0)).rg;

                          float dist = distance(qt_TexCoord0, point);
                          col += color * (1.0 - dist);
                      }

                      gl_FragColor = vec4(col, 1.0);
                  }
        ";
        }

        // Because ShaderEffect doesn't allow passing arrays to shader, we will
        // convert arrays to graphical representation and pass them as texture.
        Canvas {
            id: dataCanvas
            readonly property var colors: ["cyan", "red", "green", "darkblue", "yellow"]
            readonly property var positions: [Qt.point(0,0),
                                              Qt.point(10, parent.height - 20),
                                              Qt.point(parent.width / 2, parent.height / 4),
                                              Qt.point(parent.width, 0),
                                              Qt.point(parent.width, parent.height)]

            height: 2
            width: colors.length
            antialiasing: false
            visible: false

            onPaint: {
                if (colors.length !== positions.length) {
                    console.error("Array size of 'colors' doesn't equal array size of 'positions'");
                    return;
                }

                var ctx = getContext("2d");
                ctx.reset();
                ctx.lineWidth = 1;

                for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.strokeStyle = colors[i];
                    ctx.moveTo(i, 0);
                    ctx.lineTo(i+1, 0);
                    ctx.stroke();
                    ctx.closePath();

                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.strokeStyle = Qt.rgba(positions[i].x / parent.width, positions[i].y / parent.height, 0, 1);
                    ctx.moveTo(i, 1);
                    ctx.lineTo(i+1, 1);
                    ctx.stroke();
                    ctx.closePath();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That is how it looks
[image]

I'm not OpenGL guru, so this code isn't perfect. I'll be glad if someone will edit this answer to make it better.

Answer (score 1):

Ihor's answer is good. I found that Qt actually provides an example that may be of use as well. Check out their [Squircle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-example.html) example. I won't reproduce it all here, but it creates a QQuickItem in C++ and does some custom OpenGL rendering on it. The object can then be used in QML.